# How to decipher sentry warning; "span of type Connection with operation id (null).."

Tags: asp.net-core, sentry

Using Sentry.AspNetCore in a .NET core app I get these:

> warn: Sentry.ISentryClient[0]
> => SpanId:eed7125b44901343, TraceId:bde9ab9c677f6c45a343a489f37e55c1, ParentId:0000000000000000 =>
> ConnectionId:0HMBS5J9RV0II => RequestPath:/ws
> RequestId:0HMBS5J9RV0II:00000002
> Trying to get a span of type Connection with operation id (null), but it was not found.

What does this message mean, should I get rid of them and if so, how?

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing the warnings?

Comment: >Did you ever find out what was causing the warnings?
No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

It was fixed in 3.10.0.

---

It looks like a bug in Sentry SDK. See the related [issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/1210).

There is hope that this will be fixed soon.

> The latter error in regard to spans will be fixed soon.

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/1210#issuecomment-933822947